# how to use query result (single row or multiple row) data from node-mysql

Tags: socket.io, node-mysql

I have successfully get data by performing query with node-mysql. But i cant use the query result.

My query result is

```
    {
  user_id: 'joy',
  user_name: 'joy',
  email: 'joy@gmail.com',
  socket_id: '/#glVfkRwTqKrlBETiAAAH',
  status: 1 }
```

To use this from i wrote code like :

```
 var value= [];
    value = connection.query('SELECT * FROM socket_users WHERE email = ?',[receiver_email], function (error, results,fields) {
        // Neat!
        if (error) throw error;

        console.log(results[0]);

        if (results[0].status == 0) {


        }else {
            console.log("User is online......");
        }

        //console.log("select one user sql: "+is_Exists.sql);
    });
```

But i got **errors** at **results[0].status** line. It says

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

Comment: console.log(results).  It looks like your query is returning no records...

Answer (score 0):

After searching to solve my problem i found a solution. **results** is an array of an object. So , to use this;

just call

> **results [array number ]. row attribute name**

```
results[i].status 
results[i].user_name 
// where i is an integer number
```